# Why is not Object _id of hotel save in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mern

How to fix this error ?
Here is HotelRoom Module

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const HotelRoomSchema = new Schema({
    name : {
        type : String,
        require : true
    },
    numberofRooms : {
        type : Number,
        require : true
    },
    typeOfBeds : {
        type : String,
        require : true
    },
    noOfBeds : {
        type : Number,
        require : true
    },
    sleepers : {
        type : Number,
        require : true
    },
    view : {
        type : String,
        require : true
    },
    area : {
        type : Number,
        require : true
    },
    price : {
        type : Number,
        require : true
    },
    hotel : {
        type :Schema.Types.ObjectId ,ref:"Hotel",require:true
    }
})

const HotelRoom = mongoose.model("HotelRoom",HotelRoomSchema);

module.exports = HotelRoom;
```

/////////Here is the route

```
router.route("/:hotelId/addroom").post((req,res) =>{

    let hotelId = req.params.id;
    const name = req.body.name;
    const numberofRooms = Number(req.body.numberofRooms);
    const typeOfBeds = req.body.typeOfBeds;
    const noOfBeds = Number(req.body.noOfBeds);
    const sleepers = Number(req.body.sleepers);
    const view = req.body.view;
    const area = Number(req.body.area);
    const price = Number(req.body.price);

    const newRoom = new HotelRoom({
 
        name,
        numberofRooms,
        typeOfBeds,
        noOfBeds,
        sleepers,
        view,
        area,
        price,
        hotelId
    })

    newRoom.save().then(()=>{
        res.json("New Room Added")
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    })
})
```

//// here is the postman values
http://localhost:8070/hotel/6432d331380ef51c5e992af1/addroom

```
{
  "name": "Deluxe Suite",
  "numberofRooms": 10,
  "typeOfBeds": "King",
  "noOfBeds": 2,
  "sleepers": 2,
  "view": "Ocean View",
  "area": 60,
  "price": 200
}
```

Here is what saved on mongoDB
_id : ObjectId('643662e1e5b1f15e6720c1be')
name : "Deluxe Suite"
numberofRooms : 10
typeOfBeds : "King"
noOfBeds : 2
sleepers : 2
view : "Ocean View"
area : 60
price : 200
__v
0

I need get hotelId to the database

Answer (score 2):

found the answer `let hotel = req.params.id;` need to be changed to

```
let hotel = req.params.hotelId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your field in the `HotelRoomSchema` is called `hotel` not `hotelId`. So you need to construct it like so:

```
new HotelRoom({ hotel: hotelId, name, numberOfRooms, ... })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `hotelId` into `hotel`

```js
router.route("/:hotelId/addroom").post((req,res) =>{

    let hotel = req.params.id;
    const name = req.body.name;
    const numberofRooms = Number(req.body.numberofRooms);
    const typeOfBeds = req.body.typeOfBeds;
    const noOfBeds = Number(req.body.noOfBeds);
    const sleepers = Number(req.body.sleepers);
    const view = req.body.view;
    const area = Number(req.body.area);
    const price = Number(req.body.price);

    const newRoom = new HotelRoom({
 
        name,
        numberofRooms,
        typeOfBeds,
        noOfBeds,
        sleepers,
        view,
        area,
        price,
        hotel
    })

    newRoom.save().then(()=>{
        res.json("New Room Added")
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

HotelRoom field name is hotel..But you save field name is hotelId..Please change to hotelId to hotel.

const newRoom = new HotelRoom({

```
    name,
    numberofRooms,
    typeOfBeds,
    noOfBeds,
    sleepers,
    view,
    area,
    price,
    hotel : hotelId
})
```